# Recursive Nested Array Type: Can it be done?

Tags: typescript

I'm on TypeScript 3.0.3, and this works as expected:

```
interface IndefiniteNestedArray<T> extends Array<T | IndefiniteNestedArray<T>> {}

let arr: IndefiniteNestedArray<string> = [ [ [ [9001] ] ] ]; // 4 levels
//
// type 'number[][][][]' is not assignable to type 'IndefiniteNestedArray<string>'.
//
```

But for some reason, when I nest it one dimension further, the type error goes away... when it obviously shouldn't:

```
interface IndefiniteNestedArray<T> extends Array<T | IndefiniteNestedArray<T>> {}

let arr: IndefiniteNestedArray<string> = [ [ [ [ [9001] ] ] ] ]; // 5 levels
// all good!...????
```

So either I've hit a design limitation of Typescript and you can create recursively typed Array only 4 levels deep, or I'm doing something wrong.

And to add to the mystery (or perhaps it's a clue?), things get even weirder when you reassign a variable of this type. Check out [this code on the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IndefiniteNestedArray%3CT%3E%20extends%20Array%3CT%20%7C%20IndefiniteNestedArray%3CT%3E%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F*%0D%0A%20%20%20%20TRY%20UNCOMMENTING%20EACH%20SECTION%20INDIVIDUALLY%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20IF%20MORE%20THAN%20ONE%20IS%20UNCOMMENTED%2C%20THINGS%20GET%20EVEN%20WEIRDER%0D%0A*%2F%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20------------------%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20let%20right%3A%20IndefiniteNestedArray%3Cstring%3E%20%3D%20%5B%5B%5B%5B9001%5D%5D%5D%5D%3B%20%2F%2F%20this%20seems%20to%20be%20the%20depth%20limit%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20------------------%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20let%20wrong%3A%20IndefiniteNestedArray%3Cstring%3E%20%3D%20%5B%5B%5B%5B%5B9001%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%3B%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20------------------%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20let%20wut_1%3A%20IndefiniteNestedArray%3Cstring%3E%20%3D%20%5B%5B%5B%5B9001%5D%5D%5D%5D%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20wut_1%20%3D%20%5B%5B%5B%5B%5B%5B%5B%5B9001%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20apparently%20it%20can%20get%20longer%20on%20each%20assignment%3F%0D%0A%2F%2F%20wut_1%20%3D%20%5B%5B%5B%5B%5B%5B%5B%5B%5B%5B%5B%5B9001%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20------------------%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20let%20wut_2%3A%20IndefiniteNestedArray%3Cstring%3E%20%3D%20%5B%5B%5B%5B%5B9001%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%3B%20%2F%2F%20unless%20it%20was%20too%20long%20to%20begin%20with%0D%0A%2F%2F%20wut_2%20%3D%20%5B%5B%5B%5B%5B%5B%5B%5B9001%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%3B%20%2F%2F%20then%20type-checking%20continues%20not%20to%20work%0D%0A%2F%2F%20wut_2%20%3D%20%5B%5B%5B%5B%5B%5B%5B%5B%5B%5B%5B%5B9001%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%3B)

If you have any idea what's going on, I'd love some insight.

Comment: I think it's a bug if in I have a 5 level array, errors go away for all such arrays in the file, even unde @unional's assumption shot should not be:

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IndefiniteNestedArray%3CT%3E%20extends%20Array%3CT%20%7C%20IndefiniteNestedArray%3CT%3E%3E%20%7B%7D%0D%0Alet%20arr%3A%20IndefiniteNestedArray%3Cstring%3E%20%3D%20%5B%5B%5B%5B%5B9001%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%3B%20%2F%2F%205%20levels%0D%0Alet%20arr2%3A%20IndefiniteNestedArray%3Cstring%3E%20%3D%20%5B%5B%5B%5B9001%5D%5D%5D%5D%3B%20%2F%2F%204%20levels%20if%20you%20remove%20the%20first%20this%20one%20is%20an%20error%0D%0A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a limitation on recursive types.
It cuts off at level 5.

https://youtu.be/hDACN-BGvI8?t=22m59s